# .eot not working in IE

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm importing a font with CSS. However, it does not seem to work in IE. I don't know why.

Here's my CSS code:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'bello';
    src: url('../fonts/bello.eot?');
    src: url('../fonts/bello.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/bello.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/bello.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('../fonts/bello.svg#bello') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
              }
.bello { 
    font-family: "bello", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
```

I've added .eot, .svg, .woff, .ttf and .otf to the folder fonts. It displays correctly in all browsers except IE. To create the .eot file I used this site: http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi.

I have no idea why it's not working. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

solved the problem, it was not problem of the eot file. It seems IE has a problem finding the .eot file if the family name is different as the full name of the font. In my case font name was bello-script and font family was bello. Changed both of them and everything worked fine.

Comment: You, sir, are a mighty **GENIUS**. Been trying to solve this problem for ages

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "full name of the font"? Where is this specified? You say that you had set your font name to "bello-script", but I don't see that mentioned anywhere in your code snippet...

Comment: @SimonGreen when you create a font, in the .svg file there are details of the font, under which the fullname is also a field, like the following: <json>
<![CDATA[
{
 "fontFamily": "bello",
 "majorVersion": 1,
 "minorVersion": 0,
 "version": "Version 1.0",
 "fontId": "hillrom",
 "psName": "hillrom",
 "subFamily": "Regular",
 "fullName": "bello-script",
 "description": "Font generated by IcoMoon."
}
]]>
</json>

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue. As with the other response it didn't appear to be a problem with the .eot file but rather with the font-family value length.

Changing the @font-face and references of:

```
font-family: Titillium Web Extra Light Italic
```

To:

```
font-family: Titillium Web Light Italic
```

Fixed it for me. Always expect IE to fall over for absolutely any reason...