# The font is not displayed on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face, webfonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo-Sans';
  src:  url('../fonts/MuseoSans/MuseoSans-900.otf') format('opentype'),
        url('../fonts/MuseoSans/MuseoSans-900.eot'),
        url('../fonts/MuseoSans/MuseoSans-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

That is not displayed on the Internet explorer. I take the otf file, convert it to eot, but here I am adding the third line myself. How to convert correctly so that files have this `?#iefix` ?

Comment: What specific IE version are you using? (I know there's not many people using anything other than IE11 so it's easy to assume that, but even today it is important to be clear on this, because the capabilities of IE from one version to the next are radically different, as would be the answers to this question.

Comment: What version of internet explorer? Some times IE has a problem finding the .eot file if the family name is different as the full name of the font. From [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323370/eot-not-working-in-ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323370/eot-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: i use 11 version

Comment: Did you try to check and confirm whether that font file is loaded in IE or not? Check and confirm that file is not corrupted. I suggest you to create a small sample and make a test with it to verify the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .woff format to make it work in IE11

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Museo-Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/MuseoSans/MuseoSans-900.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/MuseoSans/MuseoSans-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/MuseoSans/MuseoSans-900.woff') format('woff'), /* IE 9-11 & Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/MuseoSans/MuseoSans-900.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('../fonts/MuseoSans/MuseoSans-900.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```